# Normal distribution in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation, mean, simulation

I am trying to check what is the probability that a new observation is anomalous or not?

Suppose I have the following set of observations:

```
x <- c(11,22,3,4,25,6,7,1,1,2,1)
```

where
the sample mean of $x$ is 7.545455
and the sample standard deviation is 8.489566

Suppose I observe a new value of $x$, 111, which is anomalous because its value is considerably more than the sample mean of the normal distribution. How can I check in R that it is anomalous?

Comment: Anomalous needs to be defined; since the outcomes (anomalous or not anomalous) is binary this problem should map to a formal T-test.  Furthermore, are we making assumptions about independence, and normality with the sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to p-value of the new number based on the distribution estimate from you sample, then you can use `pt` to get percentiles of the t distribution, with dof given by your sample size

E.g.  For testing in turn `111, 11.1, 1.11, -11.1 and -111` against your sample:

```
> 1-2*abs(pt( (111 - mean(x))/sd(x), length(x))-0.5)
[1] 9.929454e-08
> 1-2*abs(pt( (11.1 - mean(x))/sd(x), length(x))-0.5)
[1] 0.683497
> 1-2*abs(pt( (1.11 - mean(x))/sd(x), length(x))-0.5)
[1] 0.4643564
> 1-2*abs(pt( (-11.1 - mean(x))/sd(x), length(x))-0.5)
[1] 0.05041264
> 1-2*abs(pt( (-111 - mean(x))/sd(x), length(x))-0.5)
[1] 2.415531e-08
```

The bit of arithmetic around it is because `pt` returns the percentiles from the left tail, and you want a two-tail level significance (high or low values have low p-values).

Comment: As I can say that when its value less than 0.4484253 (which is outcome of value 1), Does it significant to say anomalous..?

Comment: No, I just put a number of different values in so you could see the different outputs - will edit answer to make it clearer.  Anything with a low p-value is significantly anonymous.  It is up to you to decide how low you make the cut off.

Comment: You might want to try a T-distribution instead since we don't know the variance.

Comment: ok, I am new to stats can you provide me Idea why T test is helpful?

Comment: D'oh, @JonathanLisic you are quite right.  Have corrected my answer.  Probably shouldn't answer any more today if my brain is that mushy...

Comment: The intuitive explanation is that the T-distribution accounts for the increased variability due to not knowing the true variance.  A slightly more rigorous explanation is that what you are really doing is a hypothesis test on the mean where the variance is a nuisance parameter; the test-statistic $(\bar{x} -\mu) / \sqrt{S^2/n} \sim T(n-1)$ is invariant to the value of $\sigma^2$ and has some other nice properties (Uniformly Most Powerful (Unbiased) ) under certain hypotheses.

Comment: Feel kinda guilty here - @JonathanLisic should have the rep for this really.  You want me to wiki this, or put your own answer up?

Comment: @Corone don't worry about it; you did the R code which was the actual question.  Feel free to add my comments to your answer so we have a comprehensive resource.